# Repeating setTimeout in a for loop

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    celsiusToFahrenheit(i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

I'd like to make the celsius function run every second for 100 times but somehow it does not work and I have no idea why.
Pls halp.

Comment: Can you include some details how it doesn't work? Are there any errors?

Comment: this is what happens when i run it in the console:
https://imgur.com/cokFTw3

Comment: Simplest solution, change `var` to `let` (check if your environment supports it first)

Comment: Ok nice, ty, but it still does not run the function each second.
It runs the whole thing in less than a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That loop will create 100 setTimeout that all run at virtually the same time since the loop will complete in a few milliseconds.

Multiply the duration by `i` to increment it so the durations will be multiples of `1000`.

You need to use `let` instead of `var` to block scope `i`

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    celsiusToFahrenheit(i);
  }, 1000 * i);
}
```